# How to add symbols such as † ▲ □ ■ ∞ Ʌ ℑ ⊇ ≥ ◊ etc to Regex?

Tags: regex, symbols, phpbb

I use this extension to my phpbb forum to add tags to my topics:
https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/extension/rh_topic_tags/

It says to add symbols to tags I need to change Regex -but have no idea how to update it.

My current string is:

```
/^[\- a-z0-9]{3,30}$/i
```

I want to add following symbols to it:
† ▲ ∆ □ ■ ∞ Ʌ ℑ ⊇ ≥ ◊ ≤ ⊆ ℜ § ᄼᄽᄾ ❖

possibly more, is there a way to enable all symbols?

Comment: Maybe you could just simplify it to something like `/^\S{3,30}$/` which plainly allows any non-whitespace sequence of the indicated length.

Comment: You probably don't want ALL symbols as that would include box-drawing chars, for example (`╗` and the rest). Or do you want those as well?

Comment: I want all symbols, yes. Just tried /^\S{3,30}$/ - and it doesn't allow ▲ and † @SergioTulentsev

Comment: @AlanVK works for me in ruby. Maybe it's something with php's regex engine?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev honestly I have no idea, I've never worked with Regex before. I posted about it on the phpbb forum maybe someone can help there with the better understanding of that system. Many thanks for your suggestion though! https://www.phpbb.com/customise/db/extension/rh_topic_tags/support/topic/244234

Comment: @AlanVK maybe you need to escape the "\" if the regex is stored as a string? eg `/^\\S{3,30}$/`. Note that for your test you must try with al least 3 characters and no more than 30 (as per the `{3,30}` part) to see if it works

Comment: ok so @tripleee suggestion "/^\S{3,30}$/" worked, but I had to add "i" at the end -> /^\S{3,30}$/i --- thank you everyone!

Comment: final version of the string: /^[\S \- ]{3,30}$/i

Comment: `i` shoulnd't make a difference. Use `u` for unicode.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could just simplify it to something like

```
/^\S{3,30}$/
```

which plainly allows any non-whitespace sequence of the indicated length?

No final `i` option should be necessary (there are no alphabetics here whose case we can ignore or not) but depending on context, you might want to add `u`, for Unicode.